# PySpark or SQL: consuming coalesce

Tags: sql, pyspark

I'm trying to coalesce multiple input columns into multiple output columns in either a pyspark dataframe or sql table.

Each output column would contain the "first available" input value, and then "consume" it so the input value is unavailable for following output columns.

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+------+------+------+
| ID | in1 | in2 | in3 | in4 | in5 | / | out1 | out2 | out3 |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+------+------+------+
|  1 |     |     | C   |     |     | / | C    |      |      |
|  2 | A   |     | C   |     | E   | / | A    | C    | E    |
|  3 | A   | B   | C   |     |     | / | A    | B    | C    |
|  4 | A   | B   | C   | D   | E   | / | A    | B    | C    |
|  5 |     |     |     |     |     | / |      |      |      |
|  6 |     | B   |     |     | E   | / | B    | E    |      |
|  7 |     | B   |     | D   | E   | / | B    | D    | E    |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+------+------+------+
```

What's the best way to do this?

edit: clarification - in1, in2, in3, etc.. can be any value

Comment: You could follow a similar approach to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63342599/remove-null-values-and-shift-values-from-the-next-column-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test.csv")

cols = df.columns
cols.remove('ID')

df2 = df.withColumn('ins', f.array_except(f.array(*cols), f.array(f.lit(None))))

for i in range(0, 3):
    df2 = df2.withColumn('out' + str(i+1), f.col('ins')[i])
    
df2.show(10, False)

+---+----+----+----+----+----+---------------+----+----+----+
|ID |in1 |in2 |in3 |in4 |in5 |ins            |out1|out2|out3|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+---------------+----+----+----+
|1  |null|null|C   |null|null|[C]            |C   |null|null|
|2  |A   |null|C   |null|E   |[A, C, E]      |A   |C   |E   |
|3  |A   |B   |C   |null|null|[A, B, C]      |A   |B   |C   |
|4  |A   |B   |C   |D   |E   |[A, B, C, D, E]|A   |B   |C   |
|5  |null|null|null|null|null|[]             |null|null|null|
|6  |null|B   |null|null|E   |[B, E]         |B   |E   |null|
|7  |null|B   |null|D   |E   |[B, D, E]      |B   |D   |E   |
+---+----+----+----+----+----+---------------+----+----+----+
```